# Azure DevOps Azure Service Bus items stuck as Queued

Tags: azure-devops, azure-servicebus-queues, azure-service-hooks

I have a Service Hook setup that sends an entry to an Azure Service Bus Queue. After experiencing delays on processing, I noticed the items were not getting processed and remained in Queued status. After several hours, new items were processed successfully.

[image: Azure Service Hook items with Queued status]

No errors found on Service Bus Queue message processing for those that went through.

Will the queued items eventually get processed?

Comment: Thanks for answer, confirming that those entries won't get processed in the future, we can just perform the actions to trigger the requests again without being concerned of duplicates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Will the queued items eventually get processed?

I'm afraid they won't be dealt with eventually.

Any that are still showing a `Queued status` will not be picked up again by the service and will not be delivered at this point. So there is **no** method could send the request again.

As far as I know, Service Hooks doesn't use jobs to create or send notifications, only AT threads, and it runs entirely in memory. Hence if the AT machine restarts or loses memory, the notification is lost for that event and will not be sent. This could be the cause of this issue. But it is hard to determine the specific cause

On the other hand, you could also submit the [suggestion ticket](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/spaces/21/index.html) about resending the Queued/Failed event (Because there is no such feature now). It will help deal with this situation.

[image]